# Responsive Transparent Logo in Fixed Header

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how do I achieve the effect in attached image. Logo is an image and transparent while there is still a background to the top navigation.

Thus if user scrolls down, the logo "changes" based on image or color behind it.

I have tried making two divs ( logo and links) within main div ( 100% width and 80px height). If logo is 200px wide, how do I ensure the right division always fills the rest of the viewport.

```
.mainnav{widht:100%;position:fixed;height:80px;}
.logo {background:url(logo.png);float:left;}
.links{width:???;background:#272727;float:right;}
```

Appreciate any help and seeing alternative methods.

[image: website example]

Answer (score 0):

give widths of the logo and links in percentages which makes the logo container responsive.

```
.logo{
width:20%;
}

.links{
width:80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**CSS**:

```
.mainnav{widht:100%;position:fixed;height:80px;}
.logo {background:url(logo.png);float:left;width:20%;background-repeat:no-repeat:backg‌​round-size:100% 100%;}
.links{width:80%;background:#272727;float:right;}
```

Comment: How would you ensure 1) logo doesn't stretch 2) Since logo is background image with no-repeat, the remainder is going to be nothing and appear as blank space. 3) If 20% is smaller than 200px the background image logo will crop. Correct me if im wrong

Comment: .logo {background:url(logo.png);float:left;width:20%;background-repeat:no-repeat:background-size:100% 100%;} try this..

Answer (score 0):

None of the proposed solutions worked under different resolutions.

Best solution probably is to have 2000px image as header and overflow:hidden.

Thank you